# Ajax request doesn't return a response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need a little help for my ajax request. I think i don't get the good value but i have tried more methods, without success.

[image: array simple]

[image: array info]

The purpose is when we click on <kbd>Info client</kbd>, another array is displayed with more info. But I always have the last id added and not the id's clicked's row.

My HTML :

```
 <div>
    <table id="list_client" border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Nom</td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      require 'config.php';
      $clients = $db->query('SELECT * FROM client');
        
      foreach ($clients as $client) : ?>
      <tr id="<?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $client["nom_client"]; ?></td>
        <td><button name="info" id="info" type="button" onclick="display_info(<?php echo $client['id_client']; ?>);">Info client</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="hide_info(<?php echo $client['id_client']; ?>);">Masquer client</button></td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

My JavaScript and Ajax request:

```js
function display_info() {
    $("#info").click(function () {
        var datas = {
            action: "read",
            id_client: $("#id_client").val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "function.php",
            async: true,
            data: datas,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
        }).done(function (result) {
            console.log("result");
            $("#result").text("response : " + JSON.stringify($result));
        });
    });
}
```

`#result` is a div besides the array. (to test)

My PHP function :

```php
function read() {
    global $db;

    $id_client = $_GET['id_client'];

    $client = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE id_client = '$id_client'";
    $query = $db->prepare($client);
    $query->bindValue(':id_client', $id_client, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

I think I am close but no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: You use `prepare()` but you don't have any placeholders in the query.

Comment: Is your client id value getting in to the PHP correctly? You could also check to see that the query has executed, and check whether it returned any results. How far through the code do you get before things start to go wrong? If you call your PHP directly from the browser and supply a suitable ID, what happens? What is in `$_GET` when you `var_dump()` it for debugging?

Comment: var_dump($result); in your php function

Comment: You should use `$(this)` where you have `$("#info").click(function() {...` to get corresponding rows id where the button is clicked

Comment: You have multiple items with the same `id="info"` - which is invalid, `id`s must be unique. Also, you pass a parameter in `display_info(<?php echo $client['id_client']; ?>)` but don't use it, your function doesn't take parameters. And no need to `$("#info").click` when you use `onclick`. `$("#id_client").val()`: there is no element with that `id`

Comment: `id` should be unique per `td`. You have `info` hardcoded.

Comment: A few other points that you could improve: 1) in PHP, don't print raw data in HTML but use `echo htmlspecialchars($client["nom_client"]);` or other sanitizing functions. 2) If you print JSON, don't forget to sent the correct HTTP header before with `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`. 3) I corrected your HTML and closed your first `<tr>`. By the way, validate it and format it if you can before asking for help. 4) Don't build your SQL queries with concatenation. As @SkaveRat pointed out, you made a mistake as you are using prepared statements which is great.

Comment: @PatrickJanser A closing [<tr>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) "_may be omitted if the `<tr>` element is immediately followed by a `<tr>` element_"

Comment: @brombeer, yes, I know, but still, it would not be logical to have `<tr>` followed by `<tr id="<?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?>">`. In this case we could remove the `<tr>` before it. I find it clearer and more readable to just close it with `</tr>` as we usually do.

Comment: Thank for help and your patience guys. Sorry about my mystakes and my bad english. 

It was very helpful but my "console.log" or "var_dump" in my php don't return anything. 
Of course, i apply your corrections.

My others functions works so the files are connected.  
I am thinking about a trouble of format 's displayed.

Answer (score 3):

**Issues:**

- **#1** `<tr id="<?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?>">`

In the above code, how will you dynamically get the id of the client when trying to use it in Javascript?

- **#2** `<td><button name="info" id="info" type="button" onclick="display_info(<?php echo $client['id_client']; ?>);">Info client</button></td>`

Above code will make all buttons have same id which is `info`. `id` needs to unique per HTML element.

- **#3** `id_client: $("#id_client").val(),`.

There is no element with `id` as `id_client`.

- **#4** `function display_info() { $("#info").click(function () {`.

You are attaching an onclick as well as a click event listener which is not required. Do either of them and not both but I would recommend the latter one.

- **#5** `$client = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE id_client = '$id_client'";`

You aren't preparing the query here with a placeholder but rather just adding the retrieved id in the query which is very unsafe since we can't trust user input.

- **#6** You also missed a closing `tr` tag.

**Solution:**

- For issue **#1**, no need to attach an `id` attribute to a `tr` tag at all.
- For issue **#2**, make `info` a `class` name instead of the `id` and remove `onclick` as it isn't needed.
- For issue **#3**, we would get the `id_client` value from the `data-id` attribute which we will attach to the respective `info` button.
- For issue **#4**, encapsulating click event listener inside `display_info` is not needed. We can directly attach the listener.
- For issue **#5**, we will add a placeholder for `id_client` to properly bind our primitive value inside the query.
- For issue **#6**, we will add a closing `tr` tag.
  **Snippets:**

**Frontend:**

```
<div>
    <table id="list_client" border=1>
           <tr>
                  <td>#</td>
                  <td>Nom</td>
           </tr>
    <?php
          require 'config.php';
          $clients = $db->query('SELECT * FROM client');
            
          foreach ($clients as $client): 
    ?>
           <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $client["nom_client"]; ?></td>
                  <td><button data-id="<?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?>" type="button" class="info">Info client</button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="hide_client" data-id="<?php echo $client["id_client"]; ?>">Masquer client</button></td>
           </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
$(".info").click(function(){
    var datas = {
           action: "read",
           id_client: $(this).attr('data-id'),
    };
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "function.php",
           data: datas,
           dataType: "json",
           cache: false,
    }).done(function(result) {
           console.log("result");
           $("#result").text("response : " + JSON.stringify($result));
    });
});

$('.hide_client').click(function(){
       let client_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
       // do your thing here
});
</script>
```

**Backend:**

```
<?php

function read() {
    global $db;
    $id_client = $_GET['id_client'];
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM client WHERE id_client = :id_client");
    $query->bindValue(':id_client', $id_client, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I applied your corrections but it returns nothing. Same with console.log and var dump. 

I think there is a trouble with the return of json s' displayed in the div... 

Any suggestions ? 

Thanks again.

Comment: @jeremy Do you see any response in network tab on your browser when you make the request?

Comment: For the end of ajax 'request :

"$("#result").text("response : " + JSON.stringify($result));
 console.log("#result");"



                    "#result " is the id of my div in my html part. 

End of php function : 
"$result = $query->fetch();
  var_dump($result);
  echo json_encode($result);"


My dev tool's console on chrome doesn't return anything...

Comment: @jeremy ok but check the network tab. There you will find the request made and response received.

Comment: Ok , no return (white screen) for the corresponding task.
I see it works but no elements 's displayed.

Comment: @jeremy Can you share a screenshot if you don't mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246731/discussion-between-jeremy-and-nice-dev).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the error you're having, but

```php
$client = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE id_client = '$id_client'";
```

should probably read

```php
$client = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE id_client = :id_client";
```

as the binding of the prepared statement doesn't work otherwise.

Other than that: Can you check which results you get from your select query and if that's the result you expect?

Answer (score -1):

you are giving the clientid over to the function display_info, you don't need to read it out with jquery... just change

```
function display_info() {
```

to

```
function display_info(clientid) {
```

and change the

```
var datas = {
    action: "read",
     id_client: $("#id_client").val(),
   };
```

to

```
    var datas = {
    action: "read",
     id_client: clientid,
   };
```

Comment: This alone won't solve the problem, there are some more errors in OPs code